# Activity not launched from inside fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment which has two buttons. I have implemented `view.OnclickListener` methods, and set `onclickistener` on both buttons:

```
    btn_password = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_password);
    btnEditar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnEditar);

    btn_password.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEditar.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then I have implemented the `onclick` method:

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnEditar:


                registerUser(empresa,nombre,direccion,cif,tel,cuenta,id );
                break;

            case R.id.btn_password:

                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: id" + "clicked Change Password" );
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), CambiarPasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;



        }
    }
```

To check that `btn_password` is clicked, I have included a log, that confirms that the button is clicked.

My issue is that the intent is not launching the activity, it opens `MainActivity` which is the activity that holds the current fragment.

Any help is welcome

EDITED

CambiarPasswordActivity code

```
public class CambiarPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String URL = "https://.../update_password.php";
    public static final String USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String USERID = "unique_id";

    private String user_uid,pass, pass2,usuario;
    ProgressDialog progreso;
private TextView userName;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    private EditText password, password2;
    public static String MISDATOS= "MisDatos";
    private Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cambiar_password);
        Log.d("CAMBIAR", "Register Response: id" + "clicked Change Password ESTOY EN CAMBIAR PASSWORD" );
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        password2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
                pass2 = password2.getText().toString().trim();
                SharedPreferences prefs2 =
                        getSharedPreferences(MISDATOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);





                usuario = prefs2.getString("ID", "por_defecto@email.com");

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass) || pass.length() < 6)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Password too short, at least 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass2) || pass2.length() < 6)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Password too short, at least 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }

                if (pass.equals(pass2) ){
                    Log.d("datis","CAMBIO "+pass+" "+usuario);
                    SendData();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(CambiarPasswordActivity.this,"Passwords don´t match",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }






    }





    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(CambiarPasswordActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish();
    }
    public void SendData()
    {

        progreso = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Changing Password",
                "Please, wait...", true);


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        Log.d("datis","CAMBIO "+response);
                        Toast.makeText(CambiarPasswordActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progreso.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(CambiarPasswordActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(CambiarPasswordActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("password",pass);
                params.put("usuario", usuario);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Comment: please add your `CambiarPasswordActivity ` code to question.

Comment: @sukhbir, done. Code included in my question

Comment: can you print `Log`  in  `logoutUser()` method and check whether this methos is called or not?

Comment: can you add a log before  if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        } and check whether it is coming or not.If it is coming comment those codes. I think it is logging out. Also make sure activity is in manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So the actual problem is**

```
 if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }
```

Your `logoutUser()` method was executing because of  `session.isLoggedIn()` returning

`false`. As the above `if` condition is satisfying and from  `logoutUser()` you are `Launching Intent` for `LoginActivity`.

Which become problem, **so you need to handle `session.isLoggedIn()` according to your requirement.**

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnEditar:


                registerUser(empresa,nombre,direccion,cif,tel,cuenta,id );
                break;

            case R.id.btn_password:

                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: id" + "clicked Change Password" );
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), CambiarPasswordActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent1);
                break;



        }
    }
```

Comment: not working, MainActivity is launched instead of CambiarPasswordActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In the activity that holds the fragment (`MainActivity`), create a method that launches `CambiarPasswordActivity`, and make it `public`.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public void launchCambiarPasswordActivity(){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, CambiarPasswordActivity.class));
}
```

2. And call this method from the fragment:

**YourFragment.class**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnEditar:
            registerUser(empresa,nombre,direccion,cif,tel,cuenta,id );
            break;
        case R.id.btn_password:
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: id" + "clicked Change Password" );
            // Call the new method.
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).launchCambiarPasswordActivity();
            break;
    }
}
```